# Syntax error using Perl DBI module

Tags: perl, dbi

I am writing Perl code and using the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) module in the file with extension `.pm`.

When importing the `DBI` module, I am getting an error like

```
syntax error at /etc/perl/Foo.pm line 13, near "DBI:"
Compilation failed in require at join.pl
```

In the `join.pl` file we are calling the module `Foo.pm` as

```
use Foo;
Foo::dbconnect();
```

and the code in `Foo.pm` is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Foo;

use DBI;

sub dbconnect {
  my $database = "DB_NAME";
  my $user ="user_name";
  my $password = "password";
  my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";
  my $connect = DBI:connect->($dsn, $user, $password)
      or die "can't connect to the db   $DBI::errstr\n";
  return $connect;
}

1;
```

I am getting the error in the line

```
my $connect = DBI:connect->($dsn, $user, $password)
    or die "can't connect to the db   $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO.

First of all, you should always `use strict` and `use warnings` to help find problems in your code.

There's a syntax error in your [`connect`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#connect) line. Try this:

```
my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password) 
    or die "can't connect to the db $DBI::errstr\n";
```

---

A word of advice: It's a good idea to name your variables after what they represent. I'd suggest `$dbh` for *database handle* instead of `$connect`, but it's up to preference of course.

Comment: When run these in command-line, it was working. But now I am trying to insert values in a join form (in the browser) to the database table using the DBI module. I changed the code as you said. But that also results in the error (500- internal server error). In the log file I found the error "Attempt to reload Foo.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /var/www/perl/join.pl"

Comment: @Sneha: There is a lot you need to do between connecting to the database and writing to it. In general you need to create a statement handle using the `prepare` method of the database handle you got from `connect`, then call that statement's `execute` method. You should read the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) and raise another question if you can't get it working.

Comment: Okay Thanks.I added a function for writing to the database        sub here_query
{
        my ($query, @prepare_array) = @_;
        my $connc = dbconct();
        if ($connc)
        {
                my $prep = $connc->prepare($query);
                my $succ = $prep->execute(@prepare_array);
        }
}
Now the error disappears.

Comment: And how can I know about the error in our database query ?                I gave query like this - $query = "INSERT INTO User VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" and data is not writing into the db now. How can I trace this error?

Comment: @Sneha: Please create another question and show the complete code you have written. The comments are not the best place to discuss this.

Comment: simbabque, it works better when you include a hyperlink to what you're talking about: [**open a new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) – Also, come meet me at [YAPC](http://act.yapc.eu/ye2012/).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using for the `connect` method `DBI:connect->(...)` is wrong.

It would be valid syntax if you used *two* colons instead of one and removed the arrow but it still wouldn't work.

What you need is a class method call, like this

```
my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password)
    or die "can't connect to the db: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Comment: +1 for the method call and the explanation about the syntax validity.